# Excel VBA 2003 - autopopulating dates based on keywords

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon,

I'm new to this forum and VBA too but know the very basics. I have searched everywhere but can't seem to find the correct code.

I basically have a spreadsheet which deals with my jobs and it has an "Open" & "Closed" and need dates populating when these are selected.

```
Column B = "Open" & "Closed" - this is done in a list format
Column D = Date opened which needs to relate to "Open" from Column B
Column J - Date closed which needs to relate to "Closed" from Column B
```

This needs to apply for All Columns in B, D and J. I have previous work so is it possible to have it starts in the next blank cell?

I have used the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, D As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("B:B")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            r.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This only puts a date in the column D and is triggered by typing anything in column B.

Thank you,

Jonny

Comment: Please provide any code you have tried thusfar.  StackOverflow is set-up to collaborate and help with specific coding issues; it is not a code-for-you service.  If you are having trouble getting started, try the *Macro Recorder* in the *Developer* tab of Excel.  Specific to your comment, most code does exist and is out there, though it generally takes *some* effort on your part to make the code fit your data-set.

Comment: Hi Jonny, Could you explain the result in detail a little  bit, as I understand this could be done with a simple "if" formula in excel itself, no need for coding

Comment: Also, please be specific when using terms for the spreadsheet.  Columns B, D, & J, have something applied for all Rows; above you state Row B, Row D, and Row J.  If you can update your post to be consistent, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Apologies, i have updated my original post with amendments and code i was trying. 

@ApurvPawar, If its easier with the IF function that would be great. If column B says Open then i need a date populating in column D and if it says closed (column B again) then i need column J populating with the current date

Answer (score 0):

put the  formula =IF(B2="Open","Date","") in cell b2 and drag down till end. put formula =IF(B3="Closed",TODAY(),"") in cell j2 and drag down till end. Your statement " column B says Open then i need a date populating in column D ". Which date you are mentioning here ? Let me know if this is what you need

Comment: The danger with putting TODAY() in, is if OP wants a static date entered.  It sounds like they may want a hard coded value returned to the cell as opposed to a function which may recalculate based on certain events. Worth checking.